# why can't I display txt file in textArea created with fxml?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to display a txt file in a textArea contained in an anchor pane that has been created using FXML. but the file is not being displayed

I created my own class to manage files. I have tried putting the code to display the txt file inside the initializer() but it has not worked

```
This is my fxml file
```

```
<AnchorPane id="MainPane" fx:id="mainPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="403.0"prefWidth="700.0"xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <AnchorPane id="notesPane" fx:id="notePanel" layoutY="53.0" 
onDragDetected="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="700.0" style="-fx-background-color: black; -fx-background-radius: 5;" visible="false">
      <children>
         <TextArea id="notesTextArea" fx:id="notesTextArea" layoutX="179.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="340.0" prefWidth="515.0" wrapText="true">
         </TextArea>
      </children>
   </AnchorPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
This is my Java controller file
```

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    private File io;
    File[] txtFile;
    String[] titles;
    Scanner reader;

    @javafx.fxml.FXML
    private javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane notePanel;
    @javafx.fxml.FXML
    private javafx.scene.control.TextArea notesTextArea;
    @javafx.fxml.FXML
    private javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane mainPane;

    private void initializeIO() {
        io = new File("TxtFile");

        String word="";
        try{
            reader=new Scanner(file);
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                word+=reader.nextLine()+"\n";
            }
        }catch (IOException error) {

        }

        String[] everything = word.split("\n");
        String txtAreaContent = "";

        for (String fileContents:everything) {
            txtAreaContent += fileContents + "\n";
        }
        notesTextArea.setText(txtAreaContent);
    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        initializeIO();
    }
}
```

The file should be added to the textArea when I load the program, however, the program runs and shows no errors but does not load the file. (the file is not empty)

Comment: You got `private String ` to start your `initializeIO` method, but you are not returning a `String`. I doubt this code can compile.

Comment: that's my bad I edited my code just before posting here and did not realize the mistake.

Comment: Never silently swallow exceptions; you may be getting an error and not even know it. At the very least, you should call `printStackTrace()`.